# Terraform Script Copy/Populate/Replicate Existing Key Vault Certificate into newly created Key Vault

Tags: azure, certificate, terraform, azure-keyvault

kindly see the below code so far i found and worked on, my main concern is to Copy/Replicate/Populate a certificate from Existing Key Vault into newly created key vault. when i run this i got Error .
Error: Invalid data source

on resources.tf line 98, in data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert-Name":
98: data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert-Name" {

The provider provider.azurerm does not support data source
"azurerm_key_vault_certificate".

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "Test1-KV"
  resource_group_name = "Test1-RG"
  
}
    
data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert-Name" {
  name         = "Cert-Name"
  key_vault_id  = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id

}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert-Name" {
  name         = "Cert-Name"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.New-KV.id

  certificate_policy {
      issuer_parameters {
        name = "MyCompany CA"
     
    }
  key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "SHA-1"
      reuse_key  = true
    }
  secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What version of the `azurerm` provider are you using? The `azurerm_key_vault_certificate` data source was released with v2.14.0.

Comment: provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=2.13.0"
    features {}
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

Comment: That answers your question then. Bump to a newer version.

Comment: D:\Test-Env\environment>terraform -v
Terraform v0.13.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.13.0

Comment: i can't find the latest version here https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html

Comment: That's how you download core Terraform. Changing the version constraint in your first reply will automatically download the version specified.

Comment: Done new version install i used terraform init (sorry i am new)

Comment: now i got new issue when i run terraform apply -var-file parameters.tfvars it is going to create everything new instead of updating existing one.

Comment: That's a separate problem and should be raised as a separate question. It's almost certainly related to state though so I suggest reading up on state management if you are new to Terraform. If you're still stuck after that then ask another question.

Comment: sure thanks the version issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by @ydaetskcoR's comment, add it as the answer to close the question:

The `azurerm_key_vault_certificate data` source was released with [v2.14.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.14.0/CHANGELOG.md). The version of `azurerm` is needed to be 2.14.0 or above.

As an example:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "= 2.14.0"
}
# ... other configuration ...
```

For more details about azurerm, see this [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest).